# Starting android development with php on windows

Tags: php, android, windows, scripting, android-emulator

I want to develop Android apps using PHP and Javascript. I am working on Windows XP SP2.

Do i need the complete Android SDK or just the Android Scripting Environment (ASE)?  I have downloaded the `SL4A.apk` (Android Scripting Environment), `PhpForAndroid.apk` and Android emulator (just the emulator) but it runs very slow and i dont know how to install `SL4A.apk` and `PhpForAndroid.apk` on it. What else would i need for app development? I dont want to develop in `java` so i dont think i should need Eclipse or NetBeans.

Also, how i can i create an AVD(Android Virtual Device) for the emulator?

Comment: I'm not sure in what culture or language backticks are used to quote proper nouns or names. Also, Android apps aren't developed in PHP/JavaScript. They're developed in Java.

Comment: @BoltClock: they can be developed in PHP have a look at [this](http://www.phpforandroid.net/)

Comment: lovesh: your link says it: "make PHP development in Android " which means developing a php application in android and not developing android apps using php!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develope an android app, you should install an Java-IDE and the Android SDK. You dont need PHP for that.

As IDE I suggest eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2
Get the SDK and more information about it there: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Have a great start! :)

Comment: @Stuck:i dont know java and dont want to learn it when PHP can do the job. just wanted to know if i need the SDK for android scripting environment.

Comment: sorry, but... you cannot use php to develop android apps. That does not make any sense. You could only run php on an android device...but even this is strange to me :D

Comment: @Stuck - Are you familiar with [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)? From the introduction: "Scripting Layer for Android (SL4A) brings scripting languages to Android by allowing you to edit and execute scripts and interactive interpreters directly on the Android device." It allows PHP scripts running on the phone to access Java code using RPC. You can indeed build Android apps using PHP (layered above Java).

Comment: @Ted Hopp: It still is not about developing an Android app in a scripting language, but about running scripts in other languages on android. And lovesh posted right at the beginning "I want to develop Android apps using PHP and Javascript. " which does not make any sense.

Comment: @Stuck - I don't understand why this doesn't make sense. What's the difference between "develop Android apps using PHP and Javascript" and "edit and execute scripts ... directly on the Android device."? Granted, the scripts are launched from within SL4A instead of from the launch screen, but that doesn't mean that they can't be applications. They can be started as a service, etc.

Comment: yeah, I did not say that they aren'T applications. The difference is that in the "php-case" u develop an php-app running in an php enviornment ON android. But an android app itself can only be developed in java. Well, of course.. you could write a php script which puts out java code if you like^^

Comment: @Stuck: can u tell me how can i execute an `apk` from the emulator. i dont have the `SDK` but i have the emulator. i need to run `SL4A.apk`

Comment: @ lovesh: you need the SDK! Then run: adb -s emulator-5556 install yourAndroidApp.apk (where emulator-5556 is your running emulator device)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this book extract](http://android-scripting.googlecode.com/files/Practical_Android_Projects_Ch05_Introducing_SL4A.pdf), you need to install the SDK so you can create AVDs and run the emulator. The instructions for configuring the development environment after downloading SL4A start on page 5.

Comment: [this link](http://www.phpforandroid.net/) says that you need only the emulator but when i ran the emulator i couldn't figure out how to execute `SL4A.apk`

Comment: You need to install SL4A.apk on the emulator. With the emulator running, open a command prompt and execute `adb install SL4A.apk`. That should install it and then you can run it from the launch screen.